# How implement Tikz blocks with table side by side on beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I tried to implement a Tikz graph with a table side by side, but I don't know why it's not working

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
      \begin{frame}
        
        \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,text width=2.5cm,align=center}]
            \node[box] (a) {ROBOT};
            \node[box,right=of a] (b) {UNITE DE CONTROLE};
            \node[box,below=of b] (c) {MEMOIRE};
            \node[box,below=of a] (d) {GROUPE \\HYDRAULIQUE};
            \draw[ultra thick,<->] (a) -- (b);
            \draw[ultra thick,<->] (b) -- (c);
            \draw[ultra thick,->] (d) -- (a);
            \draw[ultra thick,->] (b) -- (d);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{table}
            \caption{Nomenclature des pannes}
            \begin{tabular}{cl}
                \toprule
                Repère & Désignation\\
                \midrule
                A & Electrovanne pistolet\\
                B & A coup dans vérin\\
                C & Equilibrage du bras horizontal\\
                D & Poignées de programmation\\
                E & Nez robot\\
                F & Fin de course du support bras\\
                G & Manque de pression\\
                H & Disquette\\
                I & Carte DH\\
                J & Carte(s) Servo\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I tried minipage and figure solution but it doesn't work, can you help me please, a detail must escape me...

Comment: `tikzpicture` and `table` currently are in different `frame` environments, thus they appear on two pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,text width=2.5cm,align=center}]
            \node[box] (a) {ROBOT};
            \node[box,right=of a] (b) {UNITE DE CONTROLE};
            \node[box,below=of b] (c) {MEMOIRE};
            \node[box,below=of a] (d) {GROUPE \\HYDRAULIQUE};
            \draw[ultra thick,<->] (a) -- (b);
            \draw[ultra thick,<->] (b) -- (c);
            \draw[ultra thick,->] (d) -- (a);
            \draw[ultra thick,->] (b) -- (d);
          \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{table}
            \caption{Nomenclature des pannes}
            \begin{tabular}{cl}
                \toprule
                Repère & Désignation\\
                \midrule
                A & Electrovanne pistolet\\
                B & A coup dans vérin\\
                C & Equilibrage du bras horizontal\\
                D & Poignées de programmation\\
                E & Nez robot\\
                F & Fin de course du support bras\\
                G & Manque de pression\\
                H & Disquette\\
                I & Carte DH\\
                J & Carte(s) Servo\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
          \end{table}
        \end{column}
      \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Unrelated to the alignment issue, but if you add `minimum height=1cm`to the `tikzpicture` `box/.style`, you end up with the following output:

[image]

Comment: Ok I see, you used columns  and you separate it in two equaly columns. Thanks !